# Вертикальный календарь Material Calendar View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

Не думал что буду задаваться этим вопросом, дело в том что мне ни одно другое решение не понравилось. Останавился на Material Calendar View, но только месяцы меняются горизонтально а я хочу чтобы месяцы скроллились... Как реализовать посоветуйте...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не хватает конкретики. Не ясно что именно вам надо и в чём именно проблема.

Comment: Material Calendar это, вестимо, либа какая?

Comment: Обычный стандартный календарь

Comment: Ни разу такого не видел. Вы бы, хотя бы, каких ссылок приложили, скринов, может быть... В данный момент предоставленной вами информации хватает лищь на ответ: "Да, можно такое сделать, ибо возможно практически всё что угодно".

Comment: Аа извиняюсь, щас будет..

Comment: А в чём, собственно, проблема его сделать? У вас нету исходников представленного на экране чтобы в них изменения внести или вам нужен принцип построения такой разметки?

Comment: Это и есть Material Calendar View. Он щас у меня на экране, а я хочу так чтобы месяцы вертикально скроллились...

Comment: Ну... Вам надо, думаю, использовать одну из реализаций VerticalViewPager. Поищите их на ГитХабе. В качестве месяцев используйте фрагменты.

Comment: ok! Попробую...